# name attribute overriden when specifying input type="radio" as JSF passthrough element

Tags: jsf, radio-button, jsf-2.2, passthrough-elements

When using plain HTML radio buttons bound to a bean using the jsf: attributes added in JSF 2.2, I run into an issue where the generated names of the radio inputs don't match:

```
<label>
     <input type="radio" value="foo" name="a-radio" jsf:id="fooOption" jsf:value="#{fooBean.value} />
</label>
<label>
     <input type="radio" value="bar" name="a-radio" jsf:id="barOption" jsf:value="#{fooBean.value} />
</label>
```

However, when the page is rendered, the name attributes of the inputs become "[some:jsf:id]:fooOption" and "[some:jsf:id]:barOption", meaning that checking one doesn't uncheck the other! Is this a bug, or does the jsf: attribute namespace not support radio buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the `name` as [passthrough attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm) instead. It will override the implicit attribute.

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<label>
    <input type="radio" value="foo" a:name="a-radio" jsf:id="fooOption" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="bar" a:name="a-radio" jsf:id="barOption" />
</label>
```

You only need to redeclare it as `<f:viewParam name="a-radio" value="#{fooBean.value}">`, or to manually grab the submitted value from the request parameter map.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use a `h:selectOneRadio` component which then contains a series of `s:selectItem`s.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{fooBean.value}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="foo" itemLabel="foo" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="bar" itemLabel="bar" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

For a more complete sample see http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: OP want to customize the default radio button rendering which isn't possible with `<h:selectOneRadio>` (it produces a HTML `<table>` by default)